# How do I block port 1234 in localhost without killing the process in MacOS

Tags: networking, iptables, mac-osx, port

I have a requirement to close a port without killing the process to test out a certain fallback scenario. I am using MacOS and I am unable to figure out how to do this, can someone please help?

I tried setting iptable rule using pfctl, but that did not work
(Ref - https://superuser.com/questions/505128/deny-access-to-a-port-from-localhost-on-osx) :
(sudo pfctl -sr 2>/dev/null; echo "block drop quick on 127.0.0.1 proto tcp from any to any port = 1234") | sudo pfctl -e -f - 2>/dev/null